# Side menus react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So basically I am using the navigation in react native. I have two icons on each side of the main title and I want to create drawers for both but it seems as though you cant use openDrawer() to open a particular drawer. Is there another alternative to creating a side menu with expo or is there a walkabout or another alternative package I can use in addition to the navigation drawer?

```
export const CategoriesDrawerNavigation = () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='all' drawerContentOptions={{
        activeBackgroundColor: Colors.selectedColor,
        activeTintColor: 'black'
    }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name='all' component={ProductStackNavigation}/>
        {CategoriesList.map((item, i) =>(
        <Drawer.Screen name={item} key={i} component={ProductCategoriesStackNavigation}/>
        ))}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
)

export const FilterDrawerNavigation = () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='all' drawerContentOptions={{
        activeBackgroundColor: Colors.selectedColor,
        activeTintColor: 'black'
    }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name='filters' component={ProductStackNavigation} options={{
            title: ''
        }}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
)
```